# AWS S3 files not uploaded properly if total files size exceed 50GB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js

For my web application I am uploading all the files of a selected directory, if the total files size of that directory is less than 50GB then all the files are uploaded correctly but If goes beyond that then some of the uploaded files size is not matching with the actual files size (less than the actual file size).

I am using AWS JavaScript SDK for this.

Any help/input appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: posted a solution, if it helped you can you accept it as a answer so that it may help others in the future :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your single put operation is exceeding the size of 5gb you may observe such inconsistencies.

what [aws says](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/#:%7E:text=Individual%20Amazon%20S3%20objects%20can,single%20PUT%20is%205%20gigabytes.)

> The total volume of data and number of objects you can store are unlimited. Individual Amazon S3 objects can range in size from a minimum of 0 bytes to a maximum of 5 terabytes. The largest object that can be uploaded in a single PUT is 5 gigabytes.

for more 5 gb PUToperations consider using [multipart upload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/mpuoverview.html)